# How do I pass JObject from Fiddler to Web Api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, fiddler

I have function using JObject as parameter. Like this:

```
public void AddDevice(JObject jsonData)
{
dynamic json = jsonData;
JObject juser = json.User;
string login = json.UserLogin;

var user = juser.ToObject<User>();

//some operations on user and login

}
```

The question is: how do I pass do web api test user and login from Fiddler? Method is HttpPost type of course.

@edit
Im not asking how do I use Fiddler, I am asking how do I write correctly Body Request for JObject.

Comment: Voted to close this because you're asking for how to send data in a POST using Fiddler. Any answer to that is going to be a tutorial to the current version. Should anything change (including UI), any answers will become irrelevant.

Comment: I know how to send data in a POST using fiddler but I do not know how to write a request for JObject.

Comment: Ins't JObject a json object?

Comment: Well then do you have a `JObject` as your parameter type? Have the type you want, and let the JSON Converter do its work.

Comment: Ok, so when I try like this:{
"DeviceName":"name",
"StolenFlag":false,
"UserLogin":"COS"
}
It takes correctly UserLogin, but Device object is NULL. Device object contains StolenFlag and DeviceName.